# Strapi entries empty (doesn't return nothing)

Tags: strapi

I wanted to test out Strapi. So i've created a project, content types, set the permissions for my content type to find and findone, but when i try to get data it doesn't return nothing.. Here are the steps i've done :

- Use the following commande to create a strapi project : `npx create-strapi-app my-project --quickstart`
- Created my account, and created a new Content-type called "actualites" that contains a title, rich text and an image
- Created 2 entries in my "actualites" content-type
- I've tried to go to `http://localhost:1337/actualites` but i've had a 403 error
- So i went to Roles/Public and checked the permissions for "find" and "findone" for my content-type
- When i went back to `http://localhost:1337/actualites` , well.. i just have an empty array, my entries don't show ..

Here is my package.json file :

```
{
  "name": "backend",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "description": "A Strapi application",
  "scripts": {
    "develop": "strapi develop",
    "start": "strapi start",
    "build": "strapi build",
    "strapi": "strapi"
  },
  "devDependencies": {},
  "dependencies": {
    "strapi": "3.4.1",
    "strapi-admin": "3.4.1",
    "strapi-utils": "3.4.1",
    "strapi-plugin-content-type-builder": "3.4.1",
    "strapi-plugin-content-manager": "3.4.1",
    "strapi-plugin-users-permissions": "3.4.1",
    "strapi-plugin-email": "3.4.1",
    "strapi-plugin-upload": "3.4.1",
    "strapi-connector-bookshelf": "3.4.1",
    "knex": "<0.20.0",
    "sqlite3": "latest"
  },
  "author": {
    "name": "A Strapi developer"
  },
  "strapi": {
    "uuid": "116525e6-88bf-4b09-820a-37df0cb4c17d"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=10.16.0 <=14.x.x",
    "npm": ">=6.0.0"
  },
  "license": "MIT"
}
```

My current node version was 15.4.0 , but i've had an error the first time i tried to install the project, so using nvm i've set my node to 14.15.3. But it doesn't change nothing

Answer (score 9):

You probably have the draft and publish system on. When you save an "actuality", you need to publish it too (button right next to the save one). You can also disable the draft and publish system altogether. Go to the content types builder and select your content type. Click the pencil icon right next to the name of your content type. Then Click advanced settings. Then toggle the draft and publish system button (make sure that you published everything already though, it deletes drafts). Your entries will now appear.