# How i fix Strapi return empty array problem

Tags: strapi

When I want to go to my category api in the strap, it returns an empty array. I checked the find checkbox in the roles section in the settings section. And when I want to go to `localhost:1337/Categories` link, an empty array is returned. How can I solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the cotegories you created to **publish**. When you create a new entry you have to click on **Publish** after clicking on **Save**. If you don't do that, you will get an empty array when testing the API request to get all entries.

Comment: There's also [another solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65469251/412036) with a few more details.